# WordPress: Hiding user based on custom field true/false

Tags: php, wordpress

I've hacked together some code to create a sidebar widget for WordPress that displays all non-subscriber users (ie editors, contributors and admin) in a list.

It also displays a custom field for the users job title.

```
user_role
```

Custom fields are created via Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Currently this works great, however there is now a requirement to hide specific users from the list. I have implemented another field; a true/false box. When ticked, it should display the user in the list.

```
user_hide
```

Currently, everything I have tried results in displaying no users, or all users.

Below is the foreach user in it's original state that will only show users that don't have a role as "subscriber".

```
foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
{
    if(!in_array( 'subscriber', $currentUser->roles ))
    {
        $users[] = $currentUser;
    }
}
```

Now somehow, it also needs to "AND if the custom field is true" but I have no idea how  to get that but to work. In the database, under user meta, the key "author_hide" shows the vlaues "1" for true, or "0" for false.

I have tried the below but it still displays the same user list as the original despite having gone through all users and ticking/saving where appropriate:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'author_hide', 'meta_value' => '1','meta_compare' => '==' ) );

foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
{
    if(!in_array( 'subscriber', $currentUser->roles ) && $user_query)
    {
        $users[] = $currentUser;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Below is the current function:

```
function contributors() {

$allUsers = get_users('orderby=name&order=ASC');
$users = array();

echo '<ul class="authors-list">';

foreach($allUsers as $currentUser)
{
    if(!in_array( 'subscriber', $currentUser->roles ))
    {
        $users[] = $currentUser;
    }
}

foreach($users as $user)
    {
        ?>
        <li class="author-left author-light rounded-corners">
            <div class="rounded-corners">               
                <div class="rounded-corners">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ); ?>">
                        <strong><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></strong>
                        <br>
                        <?php $user_role = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'author_role', true); if($user_role != '') { echo $user_role; } ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pic">
                <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( $user->user_email, '50' ); ?></a>
            </div>

        </li>
        <?php
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Advanced Custom Fields API to fetch the custom field for each user while you're in the loop.  Here's how I would do it:

```
foreach($allUsers as $currentUser) {

    $hide = get_field('user_hide', 'user_' . $currentUser->ID);

    if(!in_array( 'subscriber', $currentUser->roles ) && !$hide ) {
        $users[] = $currentUser;
    }

}
```

Note that Advanced Custom Fields requires that you prepend your User ID with the string `user_` when you call `get_field()` so that the function knows you're not trying to fetch a post.

More info can be found [in their documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/).

Comment: Perfect, that worked exactly as required, thank you very much!